# Regular expression for a set of repeating numbers

Tags: python, regex, text

I have the following text:

```
LAST_NAME_1, Firs_name_1    Home Phone: 333-336-6514
192 generic St. 
Newton MA 02471
Status: Attender    Marital:    Married Adult:  M/F:    Env.No.:


LAST_NAME_2, Firs_name_2    Home Phone: 777-777-2205    Cell Phone: 888-888-8888
10 generic St. 
Newton MA 02471

    E-mail :    email@gmail.com
Status: Member  Marital:    Married Adult:  Y   M/F:    M   Env.No.:    5
```

I need to obtain the text after the phone numbers, but they can have Home phone, Cell Phone, Emergency Phone, Fax or work phone in different orders. is there any regular expression that can give me the text after the last phone number?, I mean in the second blockof text get the text after `Cell Phone: 888-888-888`?

Comment: is there always a newline after the last phone number?

Comment: yes, in fact the diference is an `\n` after the number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s=""" LAST_NAME_1, Firs_name_1    Home Phone: 333-336-6514
Status: Member  Marital:    Married Adult:  Y   M/F:    M   Env.No.:    5"""   ...: 192 generic St.
   ...: Newton MA 02471
   ...: Status: Attender    Marital:    Married Adult:  M/F:    Env.No.:
   ...:
   ...:
   ...: LAST_NAME_2, Firs_name_2    Home Phone: 777-777-2205    Cell Phone: 888-888-8888
   ...: 10 generic St.
   ...: Newton MA 02471
   ...:
   ...:     E-mail :    email@gmail.com
   ...: Status: Member  Marital:    Married Adult:  Y   M/F:    M   Env.No.:    5"""

In [3]:

In [4]: re.findall('[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}\n(.*)', s, re.MULTILINE)
Out[4]: ['192 generic St. ', '10 generic St. ']
```

---

```
NODE         EXPLANATION
-----------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]{3}     any character of: '0' to '9' (3 times)
-----------------------------------------------------
  -            '-'
-----------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]{3}     any character of: '0' to '9' (3 times)
-----------------------------------------------------
  -            '-'
-----------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]{4}     any character of: '0' to '9' (4 times)
-----------------------------------------------------
  \n           '\n' (newline)
-----------------------------------------------------
  (            group and capture to \1:
-----------------------------------------------------
    .*           any character except \n (0 or more times
                 (matching the most amount possible))
------------------------------------------------------
  )            end of \1
```

Comment: I don't want the numbers, I want the text after the last phone number of the block of text.

Comment: @Leonardo - Check it out now.

Comment: Thanks amit. The only thing I would recommend for people with a similar problem in the future is to add an explanation similar to the one given by @mskimm

Comment: Another question (I will make a new question for this) , what would be the expression if I want to limit the result to the next two lines after the match?

Comment: You can add another capturing group to get both lines after match. `re.findall('[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}\n(.*)\n(.*)', s, re.MULTILINE)`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
doc = '''LAST_NAME_1, Firs_name_1    Home Phone: 333-336-6514
192 generic St. 
Newton MA 02471
Status: Attender    Marital:    Married Adult:  M/F:    Env.No.:


LAST_NAME_2, Firs_name_2    Home Phone: 777-777-2205    Cell Phone: 888-888-8888
10 generic St. 
Newton MA 02471

    E-mail :    email@gmail.com
Status: Member  Marital:    Married Adult:  Y   M/F:    M   Env.No.:    5'''

import re

p = re.compile(r'[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}\n(.*)')

for x in p.finditer(doc):
    print x.group(1)
```

The output is

```
192 generic St. 
10 generic St.
```

Explanation

```
[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}\n(.*)
__________________________          <- phone number
                          __        <- newline
                             __     <- this part is group(1)
```